# windows env variables not resolving

Tags: windows, command-line, vim, environment-variables

I have the following env variables:

```
VIM_HOME: %ProgramFiles(x86)%\Vim\vim74
CMD: %USERPROFILE%\cmd
PATH: ...%CMD%;%VIM_HOME%;...
```

C:\Users\me\cmd\vim.bat

```
@echo off
start vim.exe %*
```

Prompt:

```
> echo %ProgramFiles(x86)%
C:\Program Files (x86)
> echo %USERPROFILE%
C:\Users\me
> echo %CMD%
C:\Users\me\cmd
> echo %VIM_HOME%
C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim74
```

All good so far...

```
> echo %PATH%
...C:\Users\me\cmd;%VIM_HOME%;...
```

`%VIM_HOME%` not resolved, but `%CMD%` was? And consequently:

```
> vim
'vim.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

I don't understand?

Comment: I think you did not paste something correctly, because `%ProgramFiles(x86)%` has no drive in its path, yet when you evaluate `%VIM_HOME%` somehow **C:\\** is magically introduced.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman: The variable %ProgramFiles(x86)% has the complete path `c:\program files (x86)`

Comment: @JSanchez: No it doesn't, it is clear as day: `> echo %ProgramFiles(x86)%` --> `Program Files (x86)`

Comment: @Kat: For the heck of it, enclose %VIM_HOME% in quotes when adding it to the path. Let us know what happens then.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman: Gotcha. The user might've left part of the string out.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman sorry, I didn't copy over correctly :S

Comment: Andon may have found the reason: Is you computer running a 64-bit version of Windows? If not, use %ProgramFiles%

Comment: @JSanchez Yes, running 64-bit. But Vim is installed under `C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim`

Comment: @JSanchez Adding the doublequotes yeilds `> echo %PATH%` ---> `..."%VIM_HOME%"...`

Comment: Open a command line thusly: `c:\windows\system32\cmd.exe` and run your batch file. What happens? Then `c:\windows\syswow64\cmd.exe` and run your batch file again. What then?

Comment: @JSanchez both yield the `'vim.exe' is not rec...`

Comment: Repeat the above, but instead of running your batch file, type the complete path to the vim.exe file: `c:\program files (x86)\vim\vim74\vim.exe` and see if it launches. Also, for kicks and giggles, try to rename the %VIM_HOME% variable to %_VHOME%

Comment: @JSanchez ... the oddest thing. Renaming `VIM_HOME` -> `_VHOME` worked...

Comment: I wonder if the installation added the variable to your global environment variables settings. Open a command line (again!) and type in `SET V` and hit enter. You should see a list of all variables that start with the letter V. See if %VIM_HOME% is already defined. If it is, you won't need to redefine it in your batch script. :-) Let me know, and I'll put an answer together that hopefully will help someone else.

Comment: @JSanchez no `VIM_HOME`, only `VSEDEFLOGDIR`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not even sure how to word this "answer," so if you feel you can word it differently, or add something valuable, please do so:

After many attempts (see the `comments` section under the question) to figure out why the VIM_HOME variable was not working, a suggestion was made to rename the variable from VIM_HOME to _VHOME. The end-user confirmed that this change allowed them to launch VIM via their batch script without an issue. Still, there was no "real" reason why the VIM_HOME variable wouldn't work, unless it's a reserved internal variable to VIM.